# Как получить высоту keyboard до его открытия в React Native?

Tags: react-native

**Environment:**

React-Native 0.60.4

**Problem:**

Я разрабатываю мобильный чат. Чат имеет emoji picker. Emoji picker должен быть той же высоты, что и клавиатура. Мне нужно получить высоту до того, как откроется клавиатура. Я старался использовать keyboard listeners, но они дают высоту после открытия клавиатуры. Моя конечная цель - сделать так, как показано на картинке. Как это можно сделать?

[image: Моя конечная цель - emoji picker]

**Пример кода, для того чтобы тестировать:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createRef } from "react";
import {
  Keyboard,
  TextInput,
  View,
  EmitterSubscription,
  Button,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";

const APPROXIMATE_HEIGHT = 360;

const App = () => {
  let inputRef = createRef<TextInput>();

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(APPROXIMATE_HEIGHT);

  useEffect(() => {
    let keyboardDidShowListener: EmitterSubscription;

    keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      keyboardDidShow
    );

    return () => {
      if (keyboardDidShowListener) {
        keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
      }
    };
  });

  const keyboardDidShow = (e: any) => {
    setVisible(false);
    setHeight(e.endCoordinates.height); // sets the height after opening the keyboard
  };

  const openEmojiPicker = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setVisible(true);
  };

  const openKeyboard = () => {
    setVisible(false);
    inputRef.current!.focus();
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="height" enabled>
      <View style={styles.inputToolBar}>
        <Button
          title={visible ? "Open keyboard" : "Open emoji picker"}
          onPress={visible ? openKeyboard : openEmojiPicker}
        />
        <TextInput placeholder="test" ref={inputRef} />
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.emojiPicker, { height: visible ? height : 0 }]} />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  inputToolBar: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  emojiPicker: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Удалось найти способ как сделать это?

Comment: @ДанилаНиконец, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447880/how-to-get-keyboard-height-before-it-opens-in-react-native